# Как получить конкретную ветку (или хеш коммита) на дату и время?

Tags: git

Нужно получить состояние git репозитория на определенное время.
В текущей реализации используется найденный на SO в куче ответов вариант для получения коммита, на который потом делаем чекаут:

```
rev-list -n 1 --before="{datetime}" {branch}
```

Оно хорошо работает с мастер веткой, но возникают проблемы с фича-ветками, в которые иногда домерживается мастер. Для таких веток возвращается хеш коммита из мастера, что очевидно переключает нас в состояние мастера.

Вкуривание справки принесло вариант с **--first-parent**, но я не уверен, что с ним не будет других проблем, на которые я пока просто не наткнулся.

Итого, мой текущий вариант выглядит так:

```
rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="{datetime}" {branch}
```

И мне нужен совет как лучше запросить эту информацию и что я упускаю в текущем запросе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65545/discussion-on-question-by-monk--------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Это сработает, но потребует *мер предосторожности*

То есть, вам придётся завести в репозитории определённые правила/конвенции.

Суть проблемы в следующем:

[image]

О ветке `master` git знает только то, что отмечено зелёным. Название и верхушку.

Так что из-за мерджей в некий заданный момент времени (T) нельзя точно сказать, в каком именно состоянии был `master` на ремоуте, потому что об этом попросту нет информации. Он запросто мог быть в точках 1 или 2*.

Вы завели неплохую эвристику, *следовать по первому родителю*. Для мерджей это обычно означает "идти только по той ветке, *в которую* мерджили". Но есть вполне человеческий и легко встречаемый случай, когда порядок может оказаться обратным:

- В обычной ситуации человек заканчивает фичу и мерджит её в `master`. `feature` остаётся каким был, а верхушкой `master` становится коммит с бывшими верхушками [`master`, `feature`], *в именно таком порядке*. И ваше решение работает.
- Но тут что-то пошло не так. Закончив фичу, человек перепутал порядок мерджа и смерджил `master` в `feature`. Теперь `feature` заканчивается мердж-коммитом с бывшими верхушками [`feature`, `master`]. А `master` остался тем же, что и был.
- Человек осознал, что перепутал порядок, и сделал мердж обратно, нынешнего `feature` в `master`. Но поскольку `feature` теперь содержит все коммиты из `master` (из-за мерджа выше), то происходит fast-forward (перемотка): новый коммит не образуется, а верхушкой `master` станет вышеупомянутый мердж-коммит **с обратным порядком предков**.

#### Как с этим бороться

- Если использовать при слиянии в `master` опцию `--no-ff`, то fast-forward не произойдёт, а будет создан новый коммит с обычным порядком предков.
- Если использовать pull/merge request'ы, в том виде в каком они сделаны на Github и Gitlab, перепутать порядок мерджа малореально. Особенно если каждый PR/MR подвергается инспекции перед принятием. Порядок будет прямо написан в интерфейсе, и изменения при обратном порядке веток будут совсем не теми, что вносил разработчик, это скорее всего привлечёт внимание.

---

* *И это при условии, что никто не портил историю перезаписью коммитов, но понятно, что это случай безнадёжный и один git в такой ситуации вам уже не поможет.*

Comment: Пока не принимаю, на случай если кто ещё напишет варианты, но за оформленный ответ в любом случае спасибо.